# Use v4l2loopback in docker, /dev/video0 missing in docker

Tags: kernel-modules, ffmpeg, github, v4l2loopback

I have installed v4l2loopback in the docker container using the following commands

```
apt update
apt install -y apt-utils
apt install sudo
sudo su root -
apt-get install -y module-assistant
m-a prepare
m-a update
m-a a-i v4l2loopback
exit 

cp /usr/src/v4l2loopback.tar.bz2 .

tar -xvf v4l2loopback.tar.bz2
cd modules/v4l2loopback
make
make install
apt-get install -y kmod
apt install -y ffmpeg
sudo modprobe v4l2loopback
```

The device is available on the host at /dev/video0, but not in the docker. I have to restart the docker to make /dev/video0 available. I want to use v4l2loopback in the CI pipeline for git.

I need help on how to load the device without restarting the docker.

Comment: probably this and below to test: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#device_cgroup_rules . Anyway if you can load an arbitrary kernel module from a container, there's a security issue in your setup.

Comment: @A.B could not get how the link is useful?

Comment: I read it the first time, but I don't know how to help you.